# an item in a webshop has a timestamp, if x time passed i want the item removed

Tags: javascript, time, elapsedtime

so, all the items in my webshop have timestamps on them. the date is updated every time the item is available and it will not update once the item has become unavailable. so far so good. for example now there is an item that was last available on 2010-09-25 (this is the format of the timestamp).

what i want to do now is removing this item from the listings, because it wasn't available for the past 30 days. the listings are in a div container, so all i really need to do is give the div a display:none style, which isn't the problem.

the problem is, that i don't know how to code the "if 30 days passed" thing... any help with that would be appreciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var d = Date.parse("2010-09-25")); //in ms from 1970
var now = new Date().getTime(); //now in ms
var days = (now - d)/ (1000*60*60*24); //diff / 1 day in ms
if(days >= 30){
  //hide your stuff
}
```

There are also a couple of libraries to handle date/time in javascript with built-in method for comparisons like this.

Comment: hi
the div i would like to add a style="display:none" looks like this right now:

<div class="result-box" 

<?php
var d = Date.parse("date("m-d-Y",strtotime($row['last_available_ts']))")); //in ms from 1970
var now = new Date().getTime(); //now in ms
var days = (now - d)/ (1000*60*60*24); //diff / 1 day in ms
if(days >= 30) echo "style=\"display:none\"";
?>

>

but this gives me an "unexpected T_VAR" error. obviously the variables are at the wrong place, so where should i put them?

Comment: sorry for the messy previous comment, how can i edit it nicely?